# Windows requires automatic repair after installing Ubuntu

Tags: linux, windows, windows-10, boot, dualboot

I installed Ubuntu along Windows 10 with default option. Now Windows doesn't boot any longer and offers the automatic repair. I guess I should have disabled fast boot before, which I didn't.

I am pretty familiar with Linux, but have no idea how to get windows booting again. How can I even get a proper error message?

Comment: On a properly working machine, fast boot does not cause an issue. Something else may have gone wrong. Can you do the Automatic Repair?  That was not clear. That should not harm your other partition, but back anything up in Ubuntu that you need.

Comment: Uh sry, no the automatic repair was not successful. It offers me some advanced option, like dropping into a command shell.

Comment: The only option seems to be a system reset, which I would like to avoid. I've found solutions to rewrite the EFI partition or similar things, but I am a bit worried if this destroys more than it fixes.

Comment: I have done automatic repairs before and they have worked except if the disk was bad. I would back up any information on Ubuntu and then do the Reset. The one time I did this on my other laptop beside me, the data was preserved but I had to reinstall needed apps.

Comment: @John: Thanks for your answer! The Ubuntu is a fresh install, so it's not a big deal to re-install it. "Bad disk" means that the disk has physical damage? I doubt that this correlates perfectly with installing Ubuntu. "reset" you mean a system reset?

Comment: If your Ubuntu System is working the disk is probably OK - that was just a comment on my part.  By Reset, I mean the Windows 10 Reset. If you try to stop the Automatic Repair, Windows 10 Reset should be an option.

Comment: Windows 10 Reset will remove all Windows programs, right? Also data, like configs might be affected, right?

Comment: @lumbric - Choose the option that keeps everything.

Comment: @Ramhound thanks for your hints. The system reset didn't work either. There was no proper error message, just saying "cannot do system reset". Therefore we had to do a factory restore, so all data was removed and needed to be restored. At least Windows is running again, even if it is only Win8 and we have to re-install Win10 or find a way to upgrade.

Comment: @lumbric - Create a Windows 10 ISO, from within Windows 8 launch the setup.exe, and upgrade the system to Windows 10.

Comment: @Ramhound uh didn't know that's possible. How can I create that ISO? That will upgrade to Windows 10, i.e. leaving all hardware drivers installed?

Comment: You can mount an ISO within Windows 8 and upgrade to Windows 10.  You can use the Media Creation Tool and create a bootable installation media and from within Windows start the upgrade. Windows 8 device drivers are not compatible with Windows 10